# Swift - class and func keyword

Tags: swift

What exactly does it mean for a function to be defined this way:

```
class Foo {
    private class func bar() {
         //do something cool
    }
}
```

In other words, what is the purpose of the *second `class`* keyword here?

Using Swift 2.1.

Comment: ["Swift Language Reference"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html) -> Language Guide -> Methods -> Type Methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`class` and `static` methods are invoked via the type, rather than on instances.

```
let x = NSString.pathWithComponents(["/", "usr", "local", "bin", "brew"])
```

Any type can have `static` methods, `class` methods may only occur on classes. Subclasses can override `class` methods but not `static` ones.

```
class Foo {
    class func bar() -> String {
        return "foo bar"
    }
    static func baz() -> String {
        return "foo baz"
    }
}
class Bar: Foo {
    override class func bar() -> String {
        return "bar bar"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It simply declares the function on the class itself rather than an instance of the class.

```
class Foo {
    private class func omg() -> String {
        return "OMG"
    }
}

Foo.omg() => "OMG"
```

calling

```
let f = Foo()

f.omg() => Static member 'omg' cannot be used on instance of type 'Foo'
```

So you can see the difference

Answer (score 1):

it is a class function, so you can call it on a class, no class instances. it is the same as static in java/c++

```
class A {
    public class func f() {
        print("hey")
    }
}

A.f()
```

Answer (score 1):

The purposes of the class keyword in a function signature is to declare that the function must be called on the class's type itself. That is, you do not need to instantiate an object of the class's type and in fact cannot call this function on an instance of the type.

There are examples of this all over Cocoa Touch. Take UIImage(named: String). The UIImage class provides the functionality for you to fetch an image from your bundle by its name. But there's no instance of UIImage to call this method on (and, indeed, there wouldn't be since this function call is what you're using to get the image in the first place).